# How to bold matched strings in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

There is a file containing 10000 lines.

Suppose i want to Bold last character of each line like this: 
hell**o**

as you see, the "o" character is bold.

Is this possible in notepad++?

what should I do for this?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor.  What exactly do you mean bold?  You mean `<b>` or `<strong>` at the end?

Comment: You can't do that with Notepad++, as said above it is a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Column Mode Editing](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html).

by using :

```
Alt + Mouse dragging
```

or

```
Alt + Shift + Arrow keys
```

to switch to column mode.

Comment: may you delete your answer please? I want to delete my question, but deleting an answered question may result my account being blocked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be highlighting could help you.

```
Alt + Shift + Arrow keys
```

And then

```
Right click on highlight text - Style token - choose style from menu
```